# Appending a tr element to the tbody element on the click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I'm trying to create button event listener that will add the contents of a `<tr>` element to the `<tbody>` element. Ive tried multiple methods such as `insertRow()` and `adjacentHtml()` and none seem to work. What am I doing wrong? also i am using typescript, could that be the issue as well?

**html**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-dark invoice-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="head-contents">
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col-3">Description</th>
                        <th scope="col">Quanity</th>
                        <th scope="col">item number</th>
                        <th scope="col">item price</th>
                        <th scope="col">total price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="table-contents">
                    <tr id="item-info">
                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                        <td><input type="number"></td>
                        <td><input type="number"></td>
                        <td><input type="number"></td>
                        <td><span></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

  <!-- add item button -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addItem">Add Item</button>

  <!-- delete item button -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="deleteItem">Delete Item</button>
```

**javascript**

```
// event listener to add an item
let addedItem = document.getElementById("addItem").addEventListener("click", () => {
    let table = document.getElementById("invoice-table");
    let row = document.getElementById("item-info");
});;
```

Comment: Where are you trying to add the row to the `tbody`?

Comment: at the end of it. like when you use the push function to pop an element onto a list. I want the <tr> element to appear under the previous <tr> element

Comment: yes, Ill edit the code to show the button

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-dark invoice-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="head-contents">
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col-3">Description</th>
                        <th scope="col">Quanity</th>
                        <th scope="col">item number</th>
                        <th scope="col">item price</th>
                        <th scope="col">total price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="table-contents">
                    <tr id="item-info">
                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                        <td><input type="number"></td>
                        <td><input type="number"></td>
                        <td><input type="number"></td>
                        <td><span></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
</table>
<button id="addItem">Add Item</button>
<script>
  document.getElementById('addItem').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let body = document.getElementById("table-contents");
    let row = document.getElementById("item-info");
    var para = document.createElement("tr")
    para.innerHTML = `
           <th scope="row">1</th>
           <td><input type="text"></td>
           <td><input type="number"></td>
           <td><input type="number"></td>
           <td><input type="number"></td>
           <td><span></span></td>
    `;            
    body.appendChild(para);
  })

</script>
```

Comment: For some reason it could not find body tag, but I made some changes. let addedItem = document.getElementById("addItem").addEventListener("click", () => {
    let table = document.getElementById("table-contents");
    let row = document.getElementById("item-info");
    console.log(table);
    table.appendChild(row);
});;

Comment: this still doesnt work, but I;m not getting any errors once the code is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

[image]You need to create a template and then append to it every time you click on the button.

```
let addedItem = document.getElementById("addItem").addEventListener("click", () => {
    let item = document.getElementById("table-contents");

    item.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<tr id='item-info'> <th scope='row'>1</th> <td><input type='text'></td> <td><input type='number'></td> <td><input type='number'></td> <td><input type='number'></td> <td><span></span></td></tr>");

});;
```

Don't forget the button within your HTML:

```
<button id="addItem">Add New Row</button>
```

This worked for me, let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code snippet. This code worked for me. Depending on what actually you want to archive you can/ should tweak this to your needs. Like adding an id that actually increments with each row, and making an additional function to calculate your **Total** columns.
But since that wasn't included in the answer, I leave that up to you **:)**

```js
// ARRAY FOR HEADER.
    const arrHead = ['#', 'One', 'Two', 'Three'];
    // SIMPLY ADD OR REMOVE VALUES IN THE ARRAY FOR TABLE HEADERS.

    // FIRST CREATE A TABLE STRUCTURE BY ADDING A FEW HEADERS AND
    // ADD THE TABLE TO YOUR WEB PAGE.
    function createTable() {
        var empTable = document.createElement('table');
        empTable.setAttribute('id', 'empTable');            // SET THE TABLE ID.

        var tr = empTable.insertRow(-1);

        for (var h = 0; h < arrHead.length; h++) {
            var th = document.createElement('th');          // TABLE HEADER.
            th.innerHTML = arrHead[h];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        var div = document.getElementById('cont');
        div.appendChild(empTable);    // ADD THE TABLE TO YOUR WEB PAGE.
    }

    // ADD A NEW ROW TO THE TABLE
    function addRow() {
        var empTab = document.getElementById('empTable');

        var rowCnt = empTab.rows.length;        // GET TABLE ROW COUNT.
        var tr = empTab.insertRow(rowCnt);      // TABLE ROW.
        tr = empTab.insertRow(rowCnt);

        for (var c = 0; c < arrHead.length; c++) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');          // TABLE DEFINITION.
            td = tr.insertCell(c);

            if (c == 0) {           // FIRST COLUMN.
                // ADD A BUTTON.
                var button = document.createElement('input');

                // SET INPUT ATTRIBUTE.
                button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
                button.setAttribute('value', 'Remove');

                // ADD THE BUTTON's 'onclick' EVENT.
                button.setAttribute('onclick', 'removeRow(this)');

                td.appendChild(button);
            }
            else {
                // CREATE AND ADD TEXTBOX IN EACH CELL.
                var ele = document.createElement('input');
                ele.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                ele.setAttribute('value', '');

                td.appendChild(ele);
            }
        }
    }

    // DELETE TABLE ROW.
    function removeRow(oButton) {
        var empTab = document.getElementById('empTable');
        empTab.deleteRow(oButton.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);       // BUTTON -> TD -> TR.
    }

    // EXTRACT AND SUBMIT TABLE DATA.
    function sumbit() {
        var myTab = document.getElementById('empTable');
        var values = new Array();
    
        // LOOP THROUGH EACH ROW OF THE TABLE.
        for (row = 1; row < myTab.rows.length - 1; row++) {
            for (c = 0; c < myTab.rows[row].cells.length; c++) {                  // EACH CELL IN A ROW.
                var element = myTab.rows.item(row).cells[c];
                if (element.childNodes[0].getAttribute('type') == 'text') {
                    values.push(element.childNodes[0].value);
                    
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(values);

    }
```

```css
table 
        {
            width: 70%;
            font: 17px Calibri;
        }
        table, th, td 
        {
            border: solid 1px #DDD;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 2px 3px;
            text-align: center;
            color: green;
        }
```

```html
<body onload="createTable()">
        <input type="button" id="addRow" value="Add New Row" onclick="addRow()" />
    </p>

    <!--THE CONTAINER WHERE WE'll ADD THE DYNAMIC TABLE-->
    <div id="cont"></div>

    <p><input type="button" id="bt" value="Sumbit Data" onclick="sumbit()" /></p>
</body>
```